# Creating a matrix with rows or columns having different sd and mu

Tags: r, matrix, mean, standard-deviation

Rather new to R. I've figured out how to create a matrix, but am having difficulty with making the rows have different standard deviation and mean.

For example,

```
row 1: mu = 3.5, SD = 0.5
row 2: mu = 4, SD = 1
...
```

My code so far is as follows:

```
n = 5
k = 5
mu = 3.5
stdev = 0.5
dat = rnorm(n*k, mu, stdev)
sample = matrix(data=dat, nrow=n, ncol=k)
```

Do I need to make separate matrices and somehow combine them into one?

Comment: How many rows and columns are you planning to have?

Comment: Variable, from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to call `rnorm` repeatedly in a loop. R is vectorized and so are the `*dist` functions.
The following will do what you want.

```
n <- 2
k <- 5
mu <- c(3.5, 4)
stdev <- c(0.5, 1)

set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
dat <- rnorm(2*k, mean = mu, sd = stdev)
sample.mat <- matrix(data = dat, nrow = n, ncol = k)
```

Note that `sample` is a base function, I have chosen another name to hold the result.

Comment: What if I wanted to change the mean and sd for columns instead of rows?

Comment: @Left `matrix(..., byrow = TRUE)`.